# How can I ignore ";" parameter in a URL, in ASP.net?

Tags: .net, asp.net, url

This should be a simple question, but I'm a beginner in `.net` and I haven't found any solution in others forums, etc.

I'm working in `asp.net`, using `VB` code for the page events. I'm using the localhost server for debugging yet.

I'm using an 3rd part users authenticator in an intranet (in a different server which I'm not able to access) to load my site. This authenticators checks user login and calls my page passing the user data in the URL. But, additionally, the URL contains a `;jsessionid=null` statement before the `?`, that is messing my page load. The message appearing in the browser is:

```
    Server Error in '/' Application.
    The resource cannot be found.
    Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its   
                 dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or
                 is temporarily unavailable. Please review the following URL 
                 and make sure that it is spelled correctly.
    Requested URL: /page.aspx;jsessionid=null
```

Eg: the authenticator calls:

```
    "http://localhost:61932/page.aspx;jsessionid=null?param1=data1&param2=data2"
```

If I test with:

```
    "http://localhost:61932/page.aspx?param1=data1&param2=data2"
```

Its OK. But, when the `jsessionid=null` appears, the error occurs.

Its seems to be `jsessionid` an argument destined for `jsp` pages, but I'm not achieving to ignore this one in `.net`.
Would I do something, like considering a session or configuring the server?

Comment: What server are you using? IIS 6? 7? 7.5? Apache with mod_mono? Something else?

Comment: So reiterate your question. You want to only ignore the the parameters appearing after ';'    ???

Comment: I'd like to ignore only "jsessionid=null" parameter, mantaining the normal query params of the URL. I must to use them to identify the user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement an IHttpModule that removes the jsession token from the request path. A simple implementation would look like this:

```
public class RemoveSemicolonModule : IHttpModule
{
    private static Regex regex = new Regex("\\;[^\\?]+");

    public void Init(HttpApplication context)
    {
        context.BeginRequest += RemoveSemicolon;
    }

    private void RemoveSemicolon(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        HttpApplication application = (HttpApplication)sender;
        string path = application.Context.Request.Url.PathAndQuery;

        var match = regex.Match(path);

        if (match.Success)
        {
            path = path.Remove(match.Index, match.Length);

            // Add the jSessionToken to the request context, so it is still accessible at a later stage.
            application.Context.Items["jSessionToken"] = match.Value;
        }

        application.Context.RewritePath(path);
    }

    public void Dispose() {}
}
```

You have to register the `HttpModule` in your `web.config` file. See [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227673.aspx) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

If using IIS 7/7.5 look at the [URL rewriting module](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/460/using-the-url-rewrite-module/) - you should be able to write a rule that will strip out the `;jsessionid=null`, which in my opinion would be better than just ignoring the `;`.

For IIS 6 there is are [third party URL rewriters](http://urlrewriter.net/) that can be used to the same effect.