# URL rewriting: server don't rewrites

Tags: iis-7, url-rewriting

I'm trying to rewrite URL in my IIS 7.0 server using the URL rewrite module, but its not working.

I must to build a rule for receive an URL from a 3rd part autentication page with a ";jsessionid=null" token that raise an error in IIS when calling my page. I'm trying to remove only the ";jsessionid=null" statement. I need the URL query statements to my application ([preceeding question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4831875/how-can-i-ignore-parameter-in-a-url-in-asp-net)).

I wrote this rule:

Pattern:

```
(http://.*);jsessionid=null(.*)
```

Action:

```
{R:1}{R:2}
```

When I test the pattern, the result is Ok. But in practice, nothing happens, like there were no rewriting module. In the Web.config file seems to be all right:

```
  <system.webServer>
      <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="refazer_url_autenticador_df" enabled="true" patternSyntax="ECMAScript" stopProcessing="false">
                    <match url="(http://.*);jsessionid=null(.*)" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="{R:1}{R:2}" logRewrittenUrl="true" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
```

When the token is in URL, IIS raise the error:

```
404 - File or directory not found.

    The resource you are looking for might have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.
```

Without the token (URL manually rewriten), Its gonna be all right.

What's wrong? maybe the rule, maybe another ISS configuration?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use Failed Request Tracing to understand better what is happening and in particular the actual value that you should test in the Test Pattern UI. See: [Failed Request Tracing for URL Rewrite](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/467/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules/)

My guess what is happening is the URL in Match will never contain the HTTP protocol, but instead start at the root of the site. Also, Is the JSessionid part of the Query String? If it is, then you need to use a Condition for that to capture that QUERY_STRING in the condition. Finally make sure that the end result only contains the URL starting at the root of the site /, and not the HTTP. That is only required when routing to a different server/app pool but requires Application Request Routing (ARR) installed in the machine.

Comment: It works! That's it... I've changed the rule to "(.*);jsessionid=null(.*)" and now the module is rewriting the URL correctly. The problem was HTTP.